# Is it advised to not play Hearthstone Android not on WiFi

Tags: hearthstone, android

Generally I have been quite lucky and had matches that worked fine, however I have had several arena matches fail to connect or become glitched in ways that make it impossible to do anything.
I have been in games where I cannot interact with my cards. But most annoying was the last game where it didnt even give me a turn, I got to sit and watch the opponent take his turn then mine, all whilst the normal timer continued to tick down.
Have blizzard given any warnings about the performance of this version? Also does anyone know how to rectify any of these glitches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hearthstone's reconnect feature, along with any of the connectivity in the game, is appallingly designed or at least based on security over usability. Consequently, a short disconnect or dropping a single packet of data can be enough to desync the game.

Wifi is naturally going to be less reliable and mobile data will be even less so. However, there are other factors at work here. Switching to a wired connection might fix the problem but it will do nothing if the problem is with the internet connection itself.

Blizzard have responded to these complaints on different occasions by pointing out that the desyncs are the user's fault for not using a perfect connection. They also warn that they do not give refunds for any disconnection related issues.

Comment: Yeah, because everyone can expect a perfect connection everytime on a phone ... I don't even have a perfect connection at home. Did they actually say that? If yes, they are damn retarded.

Comment: @YUNOWORK They don't use the word "perfect" but do claim that any and all desyncs/disconnects are the user's fault.

Comment: @Studoku: Do not confuse "not Blizzard's fault" with "the user's fault". Blizzard has time and time again identified problems people had with their ISPs, and always stated it was outside their support scope. Which it is, in all fairness. Any network issue located in Blizzard network has always been addressed as such, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Also, if Blizzard were to give refunds for disconnects, anyone realizing he'd lose a match would simply kill his internet connection and be credited back. That'd only be a worse state of affairs, not a better one.

Comment: I am not expecting anything dont get me wrong, you play the game you take your chances. I was just wondering what their official stance was. I agree that they should not take responsibility for connection issues, that is why I specified that it was likely the issue, however some of what I described seemed like glitches rather than connection issues (watching a player play in real time, yet not able to interact?).

Comment: @Flater 's comment is an incredibly important distinction, they aren't at fault here. Rage against The Man if it makes you feel good but it's not their fault. As for "glitches not connection issues", you're getting cause and effect mixed up. A connection issue occurs (cause) and the game de-syncs (effect). This leads to things like the end-turn button not being available when it should be, or your cards being un-interactable - these are glitches caused by the game de-syncing, which happened because your connection dropped